# Conditional setting in SBT project

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a multi module project in SBT (1.1.6).

My example module definition:

```
lazy val `example` = (project in file("example"))
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.11.12",
    crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.7", "2.11.12"),
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq( ... )
  )
```

Now my intention was to disable publishing of `2.11` jar, with settings:

```
lazy val dontPublish: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
  publish := {},
  publishLocal := {},
  publishM2 := {},
  publishArtifact := false,
  publishTo := None
).flatten
```

I can block all the cases, so I hoped something easy, like:

```
lazy val `example` = (project in file("example"))
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.11.12",
    crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.7", "2.11.12"),
    (if (scalaBinaryVersion.value == "2.11") dontPublish else Seq.empty),
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq( ... )
  )
```

could work, but... I get an error:

```
/path/build.sbt:371: error: `value` can only be used within a task or setting macro, such as :=, +=, ++=, Def.task, or Def.setting.
(if (scalaBinaryVersion.value == "2.11") dontPublish else Seq.empty).flatten,
^
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
```

---

**Question:**

How do I add settings, depending on the condition (for instance, Scala version) ?

Comment: Have a look at https://gist.github.com/joescii/4431cb2185eddb699dfb79b9c910e333

Comment: @Nio I tried using it, but either I miss something or it does not work anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up adapting https://gist.github.com/joescii/4431cb2185eddb699dfb79b9c910e333
 to `SBT 1.1.6`

**My solution:**

```
val neverPublish = dontPublishIf(scalaVersion)(_ => true)

def dontPublishIf[P](key: SettingKey[P])(p: P => Boolean): Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = {
  Seq(
    //@formatter:off
    skip in publish      := p(key.value),
    skip in publishLocal := p(key.value),
    skip in publishM2    := p(key.value)
    //@formatter:on
  ) ++ dontPublishAssemblyIf(key)(p)
}

def isAssemblyArtifact(a: Artifact): Boolean =
  a.classifier.contains("assembly")

def dontPublishAssemblyIf[P](key: SettingKey[P])(p: P => Boolean): Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = {
  Seq(
    // remove added assembly artifacts and publishTasks
    //@formatter:off
    artifacts         := artifacts        .value.filterNot {       a     => p(key.value) && isAssemblyArtifact(a) },
    packagedArtifacts := packagedArtifacts.value.filterNot { case (a, _) => p(key.value) && isAssemblyArtifact(a) }
    //@formatter:on
  )
}
```

I am quite surprised that SBT is really so hard to use, but during this adventure, I have understood it's interiors more.

I just post if one would have a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an SBT expert by any means, but I had a similar problem recently which I solved by moving everything that is not a very simple statement from `build.sbt` into `project/MySettings.scala`.  The parsing rules for the `.sbt` files continually confuse me, but in a `.scala` file its just regular scala.  So you would have something like

```scala
object MySettings {
  val dontPublish: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    publish := {},
    publishLocal := {},
    publishM2 := {},
    publishArtifact := false,
    publishTo := None
  ).flatten

  val maybeDontPublish = if (scalaBinaryVersion.value == "2.11") dontPublish else Seq.empty
}
```

and then in your `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val `example` = (project in file("example"))
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.11.12",
    crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.7", "2.11.12"),
    MySettings.maybeDontPublish,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq( ... )
  )
```

You might need to pull the `scalaVersion` and `crossScalaVersion` out into `MySettings.scala` as well, I'm not entirely sure, since those are semi-magical.  Or maybe change `MySettings.maybeDontPublish` to `def maybeDontPublish(scalaVersion: String): Seq[Setting]`

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicates, you can only get to the `value` inside a task or setting macro.  You can accomplish what you are after by adding the setting `skip in publish := scalaBinaryVersion.value == "2.11"`.

Comment: actually I want to skip also `publishLocal`, `publishM2`, etc... is there a way to encapsulate multiple settings into one conditional?

Comment: I don't believe that it's possible to do within one conditional (though I'd be happy to be proven wrong).